# Contar sequências de 1 dentro de vetor em R

Tags: array, r

Gostaria de saber como contar sequências de 1 dentro de um vetor contendo somente 0 e 1. Por exemplo, no vetor `x <- c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1)`, a contagem daria o vetor `(2, 1, 2)`, que conta a sequência de 2 "1", 1 "1" e, finalmente, 2 "1".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A função `rle` é perfeita para isso. Ela conta exatamente o número de comprimentos e valores de sequências em um vetor:

```
x <- c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1)
contagem <- rle(x)
contagem$lengths[contagem$values==1]
[1] 2 1 2
```

Inclusive, embora isto não tenha sido pedido na pergunta original, esta função poderia ter sido usada para contar os tamanhos das sequências de "0":

```
contagem$lengths[contagem$values==0]
[1] 2 1
```

Para mais informações, use o comando `?rle`.

Comment: Valeu, Marcus! Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Se a resposta ajudou, considere [votar e aceitar ela](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta).